# Agile management roles

Tags: agile, dsdm

I need to choose between *business sponsor*, *business visionary* and *business ambassador*. Here is the scenario:

Jane is one the owners and managing director she is the budget holder of the project and will be available throughout project to provide input where required in the project.

Paul is one of the owners and COO of the project he will be available through project and he understands the need for having a computerized system and is supportive of using [DSDM Atern](http://www.dsdm.org/). The stock controller and assistant stock controller report to him.

Which roles should Jane and Paul fulfill?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Agile roles management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6772/agile-roles-management)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the above scenario, Jane is a business sponsor as she owns the budget and can cancel the project anytime if it doesn't meet her business goals and Paul would fit under the business Visionary role if he will be involved throughout the life cycle of the project as defined in DSDM.